# how to get SubString between parenthesis

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring

I have a string like ConsumerVisit(201) or Date(CX1). How can i get string within the parenthesis "(" ")" ?

I tried a couple of times with following codes but it crashed in substringWithRange..

```
NSRange match;
    NSRange match1;
    match = [_actType.text rangeOfString: @"("];
    match1 = [_actType.text rangeOfString: @")"];
    NSLog(@"%i,%i",match.location,match1.location);
    NSString *newDes = [_actType.text substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (match.location, match1.location-1)];
```

Comment: The crash happens because you are using NSMakeRange with wrong parameters. The seconds one should be the length of the range, not the  location of its end. The last line in your code should go as this: `NSString *newDes = [_actType substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (match.location + 1, match1.location - match.location - 1)];`

Answer (score 1):

try bellow code..

```
NSString *newDes = _actType.text;
NSArray *strArray = [newDes componentsSeparatedByString:@"("];
newDes = [strArray objectAtIndex:1];
strArray = [newDes componentsSeparatedByString:@")"];
newDes = [strArray objectAtIndex:0];
```

the value of newDes should be **201**..

i use with your value like bellow..

```
NSString *newDes = @"ConsumerVisit(201)";
NSArray *strArray = [newDes componentsSeparatedByString:@"("];
newDes = [strArray objectAtIndex:1];
strArray = [newDes componentsSeparatedByString:@")"];
newDes = [strArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"\n\n newDes ==>> %@",newDes);
```

and get out put is **newDes ==>> 201**

Comment: It works well but allocates arrays, which could be harmful if you're processing thousands of hundreds of data. The solution with ranges is much more efficient, memory-wise.

Comment: yes you are right first i think same as but after i read the quetion , here ibiren define ConsumerVisit(201) OR Date(CX1) so i put this simple example so he understand it easily .. BTW thanx @Cyrille :)

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the following code,

```
NSString *subString = nil;
NSString * myString = @" hello(1234)";
NSRange range1 = [myString rangeOfString:@"("];
NSRange range2 = [myString rangeOfString:@")"];

if ((range1.length == 1) && (range2.length == 1) && (range2.location > range1.location))
{
    NSRange range3;
    range3.location = range1.location+1;
    range3.length = (range2.location - range1.location)-1;

    subString = [myString substringWithRange:range3];
}
NSLog(@"%@",subString);
```

**output =====> 1234**

Answer (score 1):

If you feel adventurous enough you can use *regular expressions* which are practically created for this purpose. They do take a little getting used to, though.

```
NSString *text = @"ConsumerVisit(201)";
NSString *substring = nil;

NSRange parenRng = [text rangeOfString: @"(?<=\\().*?(?=\\))" options: NSRegularExpressionSearch];

if ( parenRng.location != NSNotFound ) {
     substring = [text substringWithRange:parenRng];
}
```

The pattern breaks down like this:

1. Search for a parenthesis, which is "spelled" as `\\(` in a Cocoa regex
2. ... but don't include it in the final substring - denoted by the `(?<=)` construct enclosing the parenthesis. This is called a positive look-behind.
3. After the parenthesis, take any character (the dot) zero or more times (the asterisk), but make it as short as possible while still satisfying the whole regex (the question mark)
4. Make sure that it all ends with a parenthesis, but don't include it in the result (similar to the opening parenthesis mentioned under 1. above. This is called a positive look-ahead.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out..

```
    NSString *originalString = @"ConsumerVisit(201)"
    NSRange start = [originalString rangeOfString:@"("];
    NSRange end = [originalString rangeOfString:@")"];
    NSString *betweenBraces;
    if (start.location != NSNotFound && end.location != NSNotFound && end.location > start.location) {
        betweenBraces = [originalString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(start.location+1, end.location-(start.location+1))];
    }
    NSLog(@"Sub string: %@", betweenBraces);
```

Output> Sub string: 201

Thanks @paras n @vinu for ur quick answers.